# Make field require and start with "http://" on validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write a custom validation for my `store.website`. I want the method to check if the website field starts with `http://` or `https://`. This is what I've tried:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :website_has_correct_format

  def website_has_correct_format
    self.website = self.website.downcase.start_with?(/https?:\/\//, '')
  end
end
```

This doesn't work though. For some strange reason it literally just saves the letter `t`.

What's the correct way to do this? Also, can I put a `:message` to it as well?

Comment: Won't teach you how to write a custom valudation validates_format_of is built into rails and does this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't modify the value in the validator; validators should validate the existing data without changing it.
2. The [`start_with?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with%3F) method takes a normal `String` as an argument, not a `Regexp`.

So, you can implement your validator like this:

```
def website_has_correct_format
  errors.add(:website, "Wrong website") unless website.downcase.start_with?('https://', 'http://')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`start_with?` returns `true` or `false`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with?)--given a string argument.

You're also conflating validation with setting a value--validation is yes or no; why do you set the property value in the validation method?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify data in model in validations, for this you have `before_save` actions. Validator should look:

```
def website_has_correct_format
  errors.add(:website, 'Wrong website') unless website =~ %r{\Ahttps?://}
end
```